# json.dumps() : how to escape double quotes with a single backslash

Tags: python, json, string

When I use `json.dumps()`, I get the following output:

```
>>> json.dumps("abc")
'"abc"'
```

This results in unescaped double quotes. Is there a way to always have one backslash; something like:

```
>>> json.dumps("abc", additional_param=?)
'\"abc\"'
```

Comment: `"123"` is perfectly valid JSON, if you treat it as a JSON value _on its own_ and don't try to inject it into an existing JSON string.

Comment: ...and if what you want to do is inject it into an existing JSON string, you should use `json.dumps` to serialize _that entire string_ at once, not serialize a tiny subset and substitute it in.

Comment: The surrounding `'`s simply show that the shown value is a string. Just like if you type `"aaa"` and press Enter, it will display `'aaa'`. However if you use `print()`, like `print(json.dumps("abc"))`, you will get a simple `"abc"` output, because that's what the string contains. And `"abc"` is a valid JSON (while `\"abc\"` is not).

Comment: ...so, can you show us _how you're using_ the string `"abc"` that requires you to have `\"abc\"` instead? If so, we can suggest a more appropriate change.

Comment: I'm trying to make the string parseable in Java.

Comment: `"abc"` _is_ parsable as JSON by Java exactly as it is, whereas `\"abc\"` is not.

Comment: ...I wonder if maybe you're trying to generate a Java literal _representing a string that can be parsed as JSON_? But I'd really need to see what test you're running that leads you to believe that Java thinks that `"abc"` isn't valid JSON before I could understand your question.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is exactly what you want, but it might be:

```
import json

print(json.dumps("abc").replace(r'\"', '"').replace('"', r'\"'))
```

Result:

```
\"abc\"
```

Comment: This is, strictly, what the OP asked for; but it's an _extremely_ bad practice. If instead of `"abc"` one had `"a\tbc"`, one would need to make it `\"a\\tbc\"`, but handling only `"` specifically means one misses other characters that also need to be escaped.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like what you're asking for is double-encoded JSON.

```
print(json.dumps(json.dumps("abc")))
```

...results in:

```
"\"abc\""
```

---

By contrast, single-encoding (without the REPL's implicit `repr()`) looks like:

```
print(json.dumps("abc"))
```

...and emits *the correctly-encoded JSON document*:

```
"abc"
```

Note that this is correct JSON exactly as it is; no backslashes are needed.